# Entire function with a condition.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all entire function on $\mathbb C$, such that 
$|f (z)|\le 100 \log|z|$ for each $z$ with $|z|\ge 2$ and $f (i)=2i$.

Comment: Please give hint how to solve this type ko inequality...

Answer (score 1):

Since above condition gives that f (z)=az+b.. now |az|-|b|<=|az+b|<=|log (|z|)| and above inequality holds only if a=0...so the function will be constant function....am I right...please suggest me...

Comment: Yes you are right..